# Adding Macro to an excel file using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core

I am currently developing an application which uses .net standard 1.1 class library that creates Excel files from scratch.
Each Excel file needs to come with a VBA Module attached.
How can I do this? I've tried to work with EPP Plus but it requires a 2.0 .net standard version. I also have as packages to this Closed XML 0.94.2 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4.
Also is there a way where I can run those macros?

Comment: Doesn't help but, is there a reason it must be .NET Standard 1.1? 1.1 is extremely restrictive and is only if you are required to support .NET Framework 4.5 (4.6.1 is supported by 2.0 Standard), and/or .NET Core 1 (Which shouldn't be in production really right now).

Comment: I solved it by updating the framework and using EPP Plus.